# Sound not working Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, 15.10, soundcard

I can't get the computer to play sound. Using headphones I can hear some sound and the test in sound setting works but I hear a lot of white noise.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10

I have tried:

1. to test the sound in the sound settings
2. to unmute in AlsaMixer (I could not adjust S/PDIF)

What shows up in sound settings:

```
Digital Output (S/PDIF) Built-in Audio
```

`sudo lspci` shows this for my audio device:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii HDMI Audio

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
```

I put this computer together. First time I have ever done something like this and it might be the cause of the issue.